# How to make 1d array multiplied by 2d array resulting in 3d array for python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I am worrying that this might be a really stupid question. However I can't find a solution.
I want to do the following operation in python without using a loop, because I am dealing with large size arrays.
Is there any suggestion?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,..., N]) # arbitrary 1d array
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) # arbitrary 2d array
c = np.zeros((N,3,3))
c[0,:,:] = a[0]*b
c[1,:,:] = a[1]*b
c[2,:,:] = a[2]*b
c[3,:,:] = ...
...
...
c[N-1,:,:] = a[N-1]*b
```

Comment: By magic..... What you want to do? why a matrix multiply by a vector should be a 3d matrix... what kind of mathematics you would use?

Comment: you don't get 3d array after muliplying 1d and 2d arrays
it'd just give a 2d transformation, if that multiplication is valid

Comment: It is not an matrix multiplication. But I wanted to avoid using loop and also wanted have a simple array structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid Python-level loops, you could use `np.newaxis` to expand `a` (or None, which is the same thing):

```
>>> a = np.arange(1,5)
>>> b = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3))
>>> a[:,None,None]*b
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[ 2,  4,  6],
        [ 8, 10, 12],
        [14, 16, 18]],

       [[ 3,  6,  9],
        [12, 15, 18],
        [21, 24, 27]],

       [[ 4,  8, 12],
        [16, 20, 24],
        [28, 32, 36]]])
```

Or [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which is overkill here, but is often handy and makes it very explicit what you want to happen with the coordinates:

```
>>> c2 = np.einsum('i,jk->ijk', a, b)
>>> np.allclose(c2, a[:,None,None]*b)
True
```

Comment: It seems very simple and easy. Now I also get to understand "a[:,None,None]". Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My answer uses only `numpy` primitives, in particular for the array multiplication (what you want to do has a name, it is an *outer product*).

Due to a restriction in `numpy`'s outer multiplication function we have to reshape the result, but this is very cheap because the data block of the `ndarray` is not involved.

```
% python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 18 2014, 12:50:18) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array((1,2))
>>> b = np.array([[n*m for m in (1,2,3,4,5,6)] for n in (10,100,1000)])
>>> print b
[[  10   20   30   40   50   60]
 [ 100  200  300  400  500  600]
 [1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000]]
>>> print np.outer(a,b)
[[   10    20    30    40    50    60   100   200   300   400   500   600
   1000  2000  3000  4000  5000  6000]
 [   20    40    60    80   100   120   200   400   600   800  1000  1200
   2000  4000  6000  8000 10000 12000]]
>>> print "Almost there!"
Almost there!
>>> print np.outer(a,b).reshape(a.shape[0],b.shape[0], b.shape[1])
[[[   10    20    30    40    50    60]
  [  100   200   300   400   500   600]
  [ 1000  2000  3000  4000  5000  6000]]

 [[   20    40    60    80   100   120]
  [  200   400   600   800  1000  1200]
  [ 2000  4000  6000  8000 10000 12000]]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand this multiplication.. but here is a way to make matrix multiplication in python using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([1, 2])
b = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
result = a*b
print(result)

>>>result
matrix([7, 10])
```

Comment: See [*outer product* vs *matrix product*](https://www.adityaagrawal.net/blog/architecture/matrix_multiplication).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is an [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). This operator is available in numpy as `multiply.outer`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])
c = np.multiply.outer(a, b)
print(c)
```

---

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]

 [[ 2  4  6]
  [ 8 10 12]
  [14 16 18]]

 [[ 3  6  9]
  [12 15 18]
  [21 24 27]]

 [[ 4  8 12]
  [16 20 24]
  [28 32 36]]

 [[ 5 10 15]
  [20 25 30]
  [35 40 45]]]
```

---

`multiply` is a [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.ufuncs.html#ufuncs-basics). According to the documentation of [ufunc.outer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html): "*Apply the ufunc op to all pairs (a, b) with a in A and b in B*" (here that means applying the *multiply* operator). Still according to the documentation, doing this is equivalent to:

```
r = empty(len(A),len(B))
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
        r[i,j] = op(A[i], B[j])  # op = ufunc in question
```